# How do I distribute data into multiple nodes of redis cluster?

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I have large number of key-value pairs of different types to be stored in `Redis` cache. Currently I use a single Redis node. When my app server starts, it reads a lot of this data in bulk (using mget) to cache it in memory.
To scale up Redis further, I want to set up a cluster. I understand that in cluster mode, I cannot use mget or mset if keys are stored on different slots.
How can I distribute data into different nodes/slots and still be able to read/write in bulk?

Answer (score 0):

It's handled in redis client library. You need to find if a library exists with this feature in the language of your choice. For example, if you are using golang - per docs redis-go-cluster provides this feature.

https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial

> redis-go-cluster is an implementation of Redis Cluster for the Go language using the Redigo library client as the base client. Implements MGET/MSET via result aggregation.